# Extra space occurring when hovering link in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul><a href="#">Power tools</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">Decorating</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">Plumbing</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">Electrical</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">Lighting</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">Tools</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">More products...</a></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a>
        <ul><a href="#">Handy man</a></ul>
        <ul><a href="#">Key cutting</a></ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li ul {
    display:none;
}

li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

ul li {
    list-style:none;
}

ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

ul{
    position: relative;
}

ul li a{
    display:block;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:white;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    font-family:arial bold;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(140, 0, 0);
}

ul li ul a {
    display:block;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:rgb(140,0,0);
    background:rgb(140,0,0);
    color: white;
    font-family:arial bold;
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgb(140, 0, 0);
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r6Mzp/6/**
How can I remove the extra space which is occurring when hovering the main navigation bar link? 
What i mean is when i hover a link in the navigation bar the drop down will show but the link that was originally hovered has got slightly bigger from the right. How can i stop the original link from getting bigger from the right? HELP!

Comment: First off, the elements in your submenus should not be individual `<ul>`s, they should be `<li>`s in a single `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub menu has more characters than the main navigation links which is creating that effect. In order to remove the increase in width, you need to limit the width of the navigation links. So here is what you need to modify:

```
ul li ul a {
    display:block;
    /*add this width element*/
    width:64px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:rgb(140,0,0);
    background:rgb(140,0,0);
    color: white;
    font-family:arial bold;
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgb(140, 0, 0);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Mzp/7/)

**UPDATE:**

Instead of changing the width of the above element as I had suggested, you can adjust the width on ul li like this:

```
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    width:150px;
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/djtLk/)

**FINAL UPDATE:**

Please find the updated css. I think now it wont be possible without altering any width.

```
ul li ul a {
    display:block;
    background-color:rgb(140,0,0);
    background:rgb(140,0,0);
    color: white;
    width:60px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-family:arial bold;
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgb(140, 0, 0);
}
```

[FIDDLE FOR SAME](http://jsfiddle.net/djtLk/2/)

Comment: thanks, but i need the original link to stay the same and the sub link to be the original size. i hope i make sense

Comment: @IPADDRESS this would have the original size of both the navigation links and sub links and still no column resizing. You can see the updated fiddle.

Comment: I think this is the last approach you can take if you do not want to alter any padding and width of nav bar then you would have to break word and alter the width of the sub menu.

Comment: yep its good, i will accept as answer but the sub menus push my website content and dont go over the content. any ideas?

Comment: For that I would want to see your content code maybe as a fiddle or a different question as this is a new problem i suppose

Answer (score 0):

I am on my phone,  and can't comment cause of my rep.  That apart,  make your ul(sub menu) position absolute and is patent element position relative. should do the trick.

Comment: it doesn't look like its working, any other ideas? suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the width of ul li css element as below :

```
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    width:125px;
}
```

or you may give the width for each li (ul li a) element. that will also works fine.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uw8yf/1/)

Comment: try it but it seems to make a bigger problem than before

Answer (score 0):

The size of the child objects are larger than the parents.

Increase the size to 35 in the padding.

```
ul li a{
   ...
   padding: 35px;
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    width: 15%;
}
```